# Why isn't Messenger working as expected in my submitForm?

Tags: forms, 10, status-messages

I have this custom form (which is a tableselect):
[image]
In the submitForm, there are two possible cases:

1. The user has already made a reservation and a **warning** message is displayed:
   [image]
2. The user makes his reservation and a **status** message is displayed:
   [image]
   The issue I'm facing:
   When the user selects 2 rows, if we have case 2 then case 1, everything is OK (first message is a **status** and second message is a **warning**, as expected) :
   [image]
   If we have case 1 then case 2, both messages are **warning** (which is wrong):
   [image]
   How is that possible?
   Here is the code of my `submitForm`

```
$baskets = $form_state->getStorage()['baskets'];
foreach ($baskets as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== 0) {
        $basket = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('basket')
            ->load($key);
        $bask = $basket->id();
        $buyers = $basket->buyer->getString();
        if (in_array($id, explode('+', $buyers))) {
//  Case 1
            $sMessage = $this->t('You have already reserved the basket #@tran.', ['@tran' => $bask]);
            $sType = 'warning';
        }
        else {
//  Case 2
            $buyers .= (($buyers != '') ? '+' : '') . $id;
            $basket->buyer = $buyers;
            $basket->save();
            $sMessage = $this->t('Your reservation request for the basket #@tran has been recorded.<BR>An email has been sent to you and the seller.', ['@tran' => $bask]);
            $sType = 'status';
        }
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($sMessage, $sType);
    }
}
```